# Can't use PowerMock with Robolectric

Tags: android, powermock, robolectric

As has been discussed in this link - https://groups.google.com/group/powermock/browse_thread/thread/25ba2b85d9e576f4, I tried to use PowerMock with Robolectric to mock a static method. But it's throwing some hard-to-understand exceptions.

Below is my test class:

```
package net.therap.passreset.service;

import android.content.Context;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.Robolectric;
import net.therap.passreset.util.ConnectivityStatus;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule;
import roboguice.RoboGuice;
import roboguice.activity.RoboActivity;
import roboguice.test.RobolectricRoboTestRunner;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.mockStatic;

/**
 * @author sharafat
 */
@RunWith(RobolectricRoboTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ConnectivityStatus.class)
public class TherapWebServiceClientTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private Context context = new RoboActivity();
    private TherapWebServiceClient therapWebServiceClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE);
        therapWebServiceClient = RoboGuice.getInjector(context).getInstance(TherapWebServiceClient.class);
        mockStatic(ConnectivityStatus.class);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        RoboGuice.util.reset();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin_success() {
        Robolectric.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, "");
        expect(ConnectivityStatus.isInternetConnected(context)).andReturn(true);

        therapWebServiceClient.login("", "", "");
    }
}
```

Running the test yields the following exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field roboguice.activity.RoboActivity.__shadow__
---- Debugging information ----
field               : __shadow__
class               : roboguice.activity.RoboActivity
required-type       : roboguice.activity.RoboActivity
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1/outer-class/fNext/fNext/fNext/fTarget/context/__shadow__
line number         : 16
class[1]            : net.therap.passreset.service.TherapWebServiceClientTest
class[2]            : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod
class[3]            : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores
class[4]            : org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters
class[5]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement
class[6]            : org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1
version             : null
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.determineType(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:453)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:294)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
    at org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:54)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:89)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

If I remove the `context` field from the class and replace it with `new RoboActivity()` elsewhere in the code, then the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:116)
    at net.therap.passreset.service.TherapWebServiceClientTest.setUp(TherapWebServiceClientTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:2014)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:885)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:713)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

The above exception seems to indicate that Robolectric is unable to create an application context. Any idea on how I can make both work together?

Answer (score 2):

Update your PowerMock to above version 1.4.9. I think i'm using 1.5.1 and i'm not seeing the same error. i have:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyStaticClass.class)
```

and they don't conflict.

see: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/PowerMockAgent

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try when I get time. And thanks for the valuable link... :)

Comment: no problem! don't forget to upvote and accept answer if it helps/solves the problem! :D

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to use PowerMock in conjunction with Robolectric.

In addition to the standard PowerMock jars, the PowerMock Junit Rule is also needed. It is described [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) how to grab it. I used the `xstream` classloading version, because the `objenesis` one is very buggy. This is working with PowerMock 1.5.5 and Robolectric 2.3, i cannot speak about the older versions. Also please note that the Java agent should not be included, because from my experience it causes problems.

So if you are using maven, these dependencies should be declared:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you have to setup your test class like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(Static.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private MyActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
        Mockito.when(Static.getCurrentTime()).thenReturn(1);

        Assert.assertEquals(1, activity.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: This setup will allow mockStatic and other Powermock features, but **you won't be able to mock Android system classes** as they are replaced by Robolectric's `org.robolectric.*` classes.

Comment: @PLNech true, however in a Robolectric environment, you do not want to mock Android classes, Robolectric does that for you. :) You can still use custom Robolectric shadows classes.

Comment: Good point, but I have been unable to mock android system classes (such as creating a mock `java.net.URL`) using Robolectric + PowerMock. Would you have any example of such usage?

Comment: As i said, you do not have to mock classes, you can use [*shadow* classes](http://robolectric.org/extending/).

Comment: So one should create a shadow class of java.net.URL and/or of HttpUrlConnection? Looking for examples, I find [many people struggling to test HttpUrlConnection-based requests](http://robolectric.blogspot.fr/2011/01/how-to-test-http-requests.html?showComment=1345381111621#c8608147723931439990) and affirmations that [Robolectric doesn't support faking of HttpUrlConnection](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robolectric/svQWkNFA74A/oWPc-et_F3IJ), and no successful example of doing so.
Is there anything specific with HttpUrlConnection that prevents from using a shadow class?

Comment: You should open a new question for that.